# How to position close button correctly

Tags: html, css

everyone! I am a long time web developer and designer, but this one has me dumbfounded. I have an alert (this is not Bootstrap) with a close button. It displays fine on the home page:

[image]

But when I put the same alert on the submit page, it moves the close button down:

[image]

Any ideas? Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="alert">
    <div class="alertContents">
        When you submit yo stuff, it comes up in the feed right away.
        <div class="alertClose">&times;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.alert {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DD7474;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FBFBFC;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.alertContents {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.alertClose {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: #FBFBFC;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: would you mind setting up a fiddle?

Comment: Have you looked in a web inspector to see if any new elements are on the submit page and are possibly moving it down?

Comment: @vletech Yes, I have. It's odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.alert {
 position:relative;
}
.alertClose {
 position:absolute;
 top:5;
 right:5;
}
```

this is probably what you need.
check out #4 on this link http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
    position: absolute;
```

and then add in the

```
    left: 250px;
```

EDIT: Add those codes to your css... Ohh and looking back at what was happening, you could maybe make sure there is a:

```
    clear: both;
```

function like:

```
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

or

```
    <br clear="all" />
```

Comment: Add where, use where? Edit your answer, please.

Comment: @TehJamDude I tried using an absolute positioning, but it screwed up the res of my design.

Comment: Use the clear function before and after your alert box... Maybe you can show more of the page, it would help us find the problem.

Comment: @TehJamDude, you must learn to be more precise. Not only in SO, but in work also. _Add those codes to your css_ is not best answer, you must tell name of `class`, `id`. Best way is to show that in edited OP's code.